# CakePHP afterSave not called when debug level is 0

Tags: cakephp, model

Upon using CakePHP 2.5.1, on a particular model I'm calling an afterSave. But it only works if I set a debug level >0 (i.e. Configure::write('debug', 0); ).

```
 /**
 * afterSave callback
 *
 * @param $created boolean
 * @param $options array
 * @return void
 */
    public function afterSave($created, $options = array()) {
        if($created) {
            CakeResque::enqueue('myqueue', 'MyShell', array('MyFunction', 'arg1', 'arg2'));
            CakeLog::write('debug', 'doesnt give anything' );
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Strangely, everything works fine with a debug level set to 1 or 2 which is not acceptable in a production mode. Moreover, nothing is written in the logs, so it seems the afterSave function is not even called.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this had nothing to do with the model. It was in the controller that a certain function - used to check if the user has enough credits - I called **before** the save gave an invisible error (although it returned *true*!), because of a *recursive* set to 0 instead of -1. Therefore for some odd reasons, the aftersave in my function wasn't called.